# .NET: How to send TCP Keep Alive packets while downloading from HTTP API?

Tags: c#, .net, tcp, httpclient

With a .NET/C# application I am trying to download data from an HTTP API. Even though the timeout of the HttpClient instance is set to 30 minutes, the request will time out much faster. Today I learned this is due to the fact that the .NET HttpClient does not send any TCP Keep Alive packets. (This is why I can download data from that API in Chrome, as proven with Wireshark, Chrome does send these packets while HttpClient does not.)

This is how I had hoped to get the JSON data from the API:

```
this.httpclient = new HttpClient();
[...]
result = await this.httpclient.GetAsync(url);
```

Now I did some research but I could not find out how to send these Keep Alive pings. The HttpClient does not seem to support them. So my guess is these need to be enabled on the socket when opening the connection. Is there any workaround for this, maybe avoiding HttpClient? Can I enable the Keep-Alive pings somehow on the socket? Is this a feature that needs to be enabled through the OS?

**Please note:** This is **NOT** about the HTTP "Connection: Keep-Alive" header! You can enable this for the HttpClient class but for obvious reasons it won't trigger any TCP Keep Alive packets.

Edit:
[image: Keep-Alive packets captured in Wireshark]
The requests always work when these Keep-Alive packets are being sent by the client, they will fail if not. This can be reproduced by using different clients/browsers. Best example: The Postman Chrome extension does send Keep-Alive packets, hence the request works. Using the almost identical Postman standalone client the request fails (or does not return any data) because, funnily enough, the standalone client does NOT send any Keep-Alive packets which can easily be checked with Wireshark.

**Edit:** I have found a very simple solution for this problem, see my answer below.

Answer (score 5):

So now I end up answering my own question as I just have found a super simple solution that actually works:

```
this.httpclient = new HttpClient();
var sp = ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(new Uri(url));
sp.SetTcpKeepAlive(true, 30000, 30000);
result = await this.httpclient.GetAsync(url);
```

In fact I used

```
var sp = ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(new Uri(baseUrl));
```

where baseUrl is the common document root of all my requests I am sending through a for loop.

Answer (score 2):

HTTP (unlike WebSockets) doesn't support keepalive messages, so I assume you're referring to `SO_KEEPALIVE`-style TCP keepalive packets.

> Even though the timeout of the HttpClient instance is set to 30 minutes, the request will time out much faster. Today I learned this is due to the fact that the .NET HttpClient does not send any TCP Keep Alive packets.

I don't think that's correct. The sending of keepalive packets wouldn't have any effect on timeout behavior. In particular, when the keepalive reaches the server and it sends the ack response, neither application is even notified - indeed they *cannot* be notified since there is no data in a TCP keepalive or ack.

> Now I did some research but I could not find out how to send these Keep Alive pings.

TCP keepalive packets are problematic for two reasons: they have awkward defaults, and they can be dropped by intermediate routers. The awkward defaults include a *minimum* timer of 2 hours and no guarantee of the ability to change that; fortunately, modern Windows versions do allow setting a per-connection keepalive timer, and allow setting it to a much lower value.

That said, I don't know of a way to get to the underlying `Socket` for an `HttpClient`. The `HttpClient` has a pipeline of handlers which end (these days) in a `SocketsHttpHandler`, which is actually responsible for the socket connection. But I don't see any APIs on that type that let you reach directly in to manipulate the socket, or provide an already-configured socket during construction.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting this, I would have expected that there is a way to adjust the socket settings somehow. Regarding the the effect on the timeout behavior, I can clearly see that the use of these keep-alive packets has an impact on whether the requests works or fails. (I've updated my question with a screenshot)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution from NetCore 2.1 onwards.I found the `ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(new Uri(url));` code did not work in my case, this did.

Source https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.socketshttphandler.connectcallback?view=net-7.0#examples

```cs
using SocketsHttpHandler handler = new SocketsHttpHandler();

    handler.ConnectCallback = async (ctx, ct) =>
    {
        var s = new Socket(SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp) { NoDelay = true };
        try
        {
            s.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.KeepAlive, true);
            s.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Tcp, SocketOptionName.TcpKeepAliveTime, 5);
            s.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Tcp, SocketOptionName.TcpKeepAliveInterval, 5);
            s.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Tcp, SocketOptionName.TcpKeepAliveRetryCount, 5); //note this doesnt work on some windows versions

            await s.ConnectAsync(ctx.DnsEndPoint, ct);
            return new NetworkStream(s, ownsSocket: true); 
        }
        catch
        {
            s.Dispose();
            throw;
        }
    };

    // Create an HttpClient object
    using HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
```